# Feature of CPU needed to run Javascript fast

Tags: multithreading, cpu, multi-core, gpu

This is more of a Computer Engineering question, but what is the feature of a CPU to run Javascript fast? I use to access the internet with an AMD Phenom II with 6 cores and I could almost have as much tabs open and almost everything is instantaneous. Then for the past 3 or so years, I've been accessing the internet with laptops and netbooks, which were Intel Celerons and Atoms and i just isn't like before. Supposing AMD Phenoms are comparable with Intel Cores (i3, i5 or i7s), what exactly does make these more powerful CPUs faster with Javascript?

I've always assumed them as high performance threading (Hyper-threading in the case of Intel) and multi-coring. I've thought of branch prediction for a while, but I know that most of AMD's architectures aren't as aggressive in branch prediction compared to Intels.

But does SIMD (MMX, eMMX, etc) performance also count? Does GPU performance matter?

Comment: It'd vary, but I'd suspect that single-core performance is the biggest factor when comparing CPU's with the same architecture.  This follows from most JavaScript engines basically being single-threaded.  So, a gaming-computer CPU with a few fast cores will likely outperform an extremely expensive server CPU that has many cores.

Comment: What you just said does not make sense.

Comment: @Dehbop If you are comparing completely different computers, the CPU is almost certainly less impactful than memory and SSD read/write speed. When you visit a page it has to download every piece of text and image and load that into memory and/or write to a file.

Answer (score 4):

***tl;dr*-**  This is a complex, involved issue with a lot of variance.  But for the sake of an answer here, CPU's with faster clock speeds are faster for JavaScript in most cases.  Extra cores won't help much.

#### Very simplified answer

The full story's pretty involved and would be too much to fit into a short answer on StackExchange.  Below, most of the statements are simplified, and shouldn't be taken as technically correct so much as to give a gist.

> what is the feature of a CPU to run Javascript fast?

JavaScript programs are basically a series of instructions that the CPU executes in order.  You want a CPU that executes those instructions fast.  So, get a CPU with a fast clock rate.

> I use to access the internet with an AMD Phenom II with 6 cores and I could almost have as much tabs open and almost everything is instantaneous. Then for the past 3 or so years, I've been accessing the internet with laptops and netbooks, which were Intel Celerons and Atoms and i just isn't like before.

[Celeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeron)'s are cheap, low-end CPU's.  Computers that contain them will generally be built from cheap, low-end parts.  [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom)'s are meant to be small, portable, and low-power.

Neither will give you performance desktop results.  That's not what they're for.

> Supposing AMD Phenoms are comparable with Intel Cores (i3, i5 or i7s)

They're not.  As far as I can find, they stopped making Phenom's quite a while ago, so they're old processors.  AMD chips from 10 years ago aren't comparable to modern Intel i7's.

> what exactly does make these more powerful CPUs faster with Javascript?

AMD Phenom's and Intel Core's use the same basic CPU architecture, [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), so we're able to compare them based on their metrics with some reasonable accuracy.

The big thing here is core speed, because JavaScript engines tend to be single-threaded which basically means that they only use one core.  So if you've got a fancy million-core CPU, awesome, but it won't help you.

Variations in chip features (e.g. cache, pipelining, branch prediction) will cause further variation.  Recently, Intel's been doing better than AMD with regards to this stuff, so Intel chips will tend to do better than comparable AMD chips with this sorta thing.  Usually AMD helps to make up for this by offering more cores in their CPU's, which is great for other stuff, but irrelevant here.

> I've always assumed them as high performance threading (Hyper-threading in the case of Intel) and multi-coring.

Nope.  Lots of cores and Hyper-Threading-like features can be useful for multi-threaded workloads, but not most JavaScript stuff.

> I've thought of branch prediction for a while, but I know that most of AMD's architectures aren't as aggressive in branch prediction compared to Intels.

Yup, that's a minor factor in Intel's favor.  But, you can mostly ignore it for now since it's probably not as large as other factors.

> But does SIMD (MMX, eMMX, etc) performance also count?

Depends on the JavaScript engine since that's what makes the choice between using those features or not.  But, in general, I'd expect that, no, these aren't a major source of difference.

> Does GPU performance matter?

Only if GPU acceleration's a bottleneck.  I don't think that that's usually true for most JavaScript apps.

Comment: Don't forget better branch predictions and especially memory paging systems. Javascript is the kind of indirection

Comment: If W3C won't draft a FULLY dynamic CSS version for interactive GUI, thus relieving Javascript the duty of creating interactive GUI, then you'd think web browsers will have some sort of "Javascript" compiler? Sure, it's a total waste of time if you consider that a fully dynamic CSS is an option, but nobody's even throwing around the idea.

Comment: @Dehbop It's been discussed, and there're some weird reasons that JavaScript compilation's received less attention than it might seem to merit at first.  The big thing's that JavaScript's usually sent with webpages every time a user visits, so the goal's generally to optimize to reduce server load.  If you compile, you can blow up the file size, plus compiling results in machine-specific instructions, which would put a major burden on the server to satisfy a whole bunch of different clients.

Comment: @Dehbop If you want to send compiled stuff, what you really need is some sort of compiled format that clients all recognize - some sort of common Assembly language that works across devices.  This has been a major interest lately, and now Web Assembly's becoming standardized.

Comment: @Dehbop So, you're probably more interested in Web Assembly than JavaScript itself.  Or, maybe there's a transpiler that converts JavaScript into Web Assembly, which would be pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: No, no, I don't mean compiling on the server end, I meant on the client end. Hence I said "web browsers will have some sort of "Javascript" compiler". The interactive stuff is compiled by the web browser, so on every event trigger, it will just execute the binary it compiled. If the binary is run as a native binary on the OS, then there'd be overhead, but if executed in the confines of the web browser, then its very efficient.

Comment: Also, on the second to the last post above, I meant the waste of time is when doing the interactive GUI. Of course Javascript can be use for so many other things like processing the text inputs and other things.

Comment: @Dehbop As folks tell it, client-side compilation's not too common because (1) it's complicated to implement; (2) there's not much expected reward.  This is, it's usually faster to just run something in interpreted mode than it is to compile it and run the compiled version.  There're exceptions, e.g. long-running web apps leading to an interest in stuff like Web Assembly, but I guess no one saw enough potential benefit to use their time making it.

Comment: @Dehbop Compounding that, there's a general sentiment that web-based JavaScript's pretty limited in what it can do, so if anyone does want to make a long-running app that's computationally intensive enough to merit compilation, then they should just write a normal program and have users download it.

Comment: @Dehbop Just so I don't give ya the wrong impression, I agree that client-side JavaScript compilation will be cool - I'm actually doing something that'll handle it, too!  So it's not that I disagree there, just explaining why, historically, no one took the time to make it.

Comment: I also have an idea about those web browser plug-ins (not extensions) that install into the OS and becomes a child process of the web browser. Maybe the web browser should have it's own virtual machine that takes a bytecode program and then executes that. Say a web plugin media player can be written once and ran on any hardware host as long as you have the proper version of the web browser. Now, the reason for abandoning Javascript and simply having this solution of a virtual machine is a matter of security. Working with the Document Object Model is quite safe as it never accesses host system.

Comment: (continuation): The web browser can also easily scan the Javascript anyways to check for any illegal actions, if there are any. Also there's that issue that you raised that compiled code can easily be much larger than a script.

Comment: Now, as for the "bytecode" program that I mentioned. I simply called it "bytecode" to more easily communicate the idea. What I'm thinking of is not actually bytecodes of an instruction set. That would still be slow as Java had already proven. I'm thinking of a fully referential binary code produced by compiling a very functional programming language.

Comment: How this theoretical binary code can execute multimedia and LOTS of floating points, such as the case with a web player, is still a problem, but I believe it can be worked out.

Comment: @Dehbop Do you have a use-case that's not being met by current solutions?